# full screen not working when playing video with iframe

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe, html5-video

I want to allow fullScreen video in iframe player. you can see my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-iframe-demo-forked-epiqv?file=/src/index.js).

```
  function App() {
   return (
    <div className="App">
      <iframe
        height={"315px"}
        allowfullscreen
        webkitallowfullscreen
        mozallowfullscreen
        oallowfullscreen
        msallowfullscreen
        width={"560px"}
        src={`https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4`}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

allowFullScreen - if set, applies the allowFullScreen param (deprecated in HTML5). If set, adds allow="fullscreen".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Code to display Your Video in Fullscreen.

```
<iframe src={video} allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" height="500px" width="800px"></iframe>
```

And btw don't mind the way I specified video url you can use whatever suits your needs.